# how do i show pdf in my own android application

Tags: android, pdf

I have Text can someone please tell me how do i convert text to pdf and how do i    show it in my android application. i saw there are many libraries which do the   same can some one give me the sample code for that. thanks

i have used pdfviewer lib but still didnt get the pdf.
   hear is my code -

```
    File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {  
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)  
            {  
                    return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
            }  
    }); 
    pdflist = new String[imagelist.length]; 
    for(int i = 0;i<imagelist.length;i++)
    {
            pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
    }
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String path = imagelist[(int)id].getAbsolutePath();
        openPdfIntent(path);
}

private void openPdfIntent(String path) 
{
    try
    {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
      intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your log here?

Comment: 05-09 06:50:22.651: E/AndroidRuntime(17031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pdfexample/com.example.pdfexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: i dont use any list or list i just copy paste the projct from net

Comment: the error implies that your not placing a listview in your xml.

Comment: im working on same will give the solution soon.

Comment: i know but i dont want to use a list view then why should i use listview in xml

Comment: i think i got the reason

Comment: if you dont want to use listview than why did you using this code? OR you meant that you dont want to use xml listview than you should extend your activity with ListActivity, using this you can getlistview.

Comment: this is my fault  its shame even i am using onlistitom and list adapter

Answer (score 0):

add `PDFViewer` as library in your project, copy its resources in your as guided in [Here](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library). This is working code for me. I am reading pdf from assets folder. Do customization as your requirement.

1. Download pdf reader project from above link.
2. copy all resources in your project.
3. extend your activity (in which you want to display pdf) from  PdfViewerActivity.
4. copy all methods from `pdfreader` project in yourpdfview activity.
5. Run.

Happy Coding

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "ABC.pdf");
  try {
    in = assetManager.open("ABC.pdf");
    out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    copyFile(in, out);
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
  }

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivityName.class);
  intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getFilesDir() + "/ABC.pdf");
  startActivity(intent);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read;
  while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}
```

The methods of yourpdfview activity are:

```
public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
```

Comment: But its not clear some words doesnt show perfectly .